# MySQL join two results together?

Tags: mysql, sql, join, union

I am trying to join two results of queries together in one view/table. I have tried this code which is close but the results are merged together like below. I need them to be separate columns. I've tried joins and unions but nothing seems to work right.

Output:

**SQL query:**

```
`SELECT `PARTY DESCRIPTION` 
FROM `PARTY` 
WHERE
  `PARTY CODE` IN (
    SELECT `PARTY CODE` 
    FROM `PARTY CANDIDATE` 
    WHERE `CANDIDATE ID` IN (
        SELECT `CANDIDATE ID` 
        FROM OFFICE 
        WHERE `OFFICE DESCRIPTION` = 'MAYOR' 
      ) 
    ) 
  UNION
  (
    SELECT `CANDIDATE NAME` 
    FROM `CANDIDATE` 
    WHERE `CANDIDATE ID` IN (
        SELECT `CANDIDATE ID` 
        FROM OFFICE 
        WHERE `OFFICE DESCRIPTION` = 'MAYOR' 
      ) 
    );`
```

**Rows: 5**

```
PARTY DESCRIPTION
Republican
Democrat
Giuliani
Dinkins
Ferucci
```

What I want:

```
PARTY DESCRIPTION    NAMES
Republican          Giuliani
Democrat            Ferucci
                    Dinkins
```

Schema:
[image: schema]

Comment: Please show the output you want.

Comment: What tables are you trying to get data from? And from those tables, what data do you want? Also, share your schema for the relevant columns.

Comment: JimGarrison, corrected. JustinDanielson, the tables I am trying to get data from are the party description from the party table and candidate name from the candidate table. The overall picture of databases are above, except the participant table has been dropped and replaced by the candidate table and the office table.

Comment: What happened to Dinkins?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, you are attempting to `JOIN` two queries in order to display pairs of candidate names and the parties they belong to for candidates holding a mayor's office.

You could try something like this:

```
SELECT `PARTY DESCRIPTION`, `CANDIDATE NAME`
FROM   `PARTY` p
JOIN   `PARTY CANDIDATE` pc ON pc.`PARTY CODE` = p.`PARTY CODE`
JOIN   `CANDIDATE` c ON pc.`CANDIDATE ID` = c.`CANDIDATE ID`
JOIN   `OFFICE` o ON pc.`CANDIDATE ID` = o.`CANDIDATE ID`
WHERE  `OFFICE DESCRIPTION` = 'MAYOR`
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the response. Although from what I can tell, your sql is expecting candidate id to be in the party table, but it is not. It is in the candidate table.

Comment: @Kyle You are correct, I skipped a stage by mistake. Fixed my answer accordingly.

Comment: Thank you so much. Okay now I'm going to do my best to understand that because it only gets harder lol.

Comment: If you want Dinkins with no party affiliation you will need a left-join.  I believe you'll want to switch the order of the first two joins (`CANDIDATE` first, followed by `PARTY CANDIDATE`) and make the second join a `left join` to return all candidates regardless of whether they have an associated party row.